# How to start new activity in corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am new on Corona and worked with android sdk on Eclipse but i don't know how to pass from one activity to another in this one? What do you we use for this on Corona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have control over activities of your app when using Corona SDK.

What you need is the [StoryBoard API](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/storyboard) which helps you to manage difference scenes.
Here are a few links regarding storyboard.

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/11/14/introducing-the-storyboard-api/

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/03/27/storyboard-scene-events-explained/

http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/storyboard

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/11/16/common-storyboard-api-questions/

Another unofficial but really efficient and useful method is the Director class

http://maniacdev.com/2011/05/using-the-director-class-for-easy-switching-in-the-corona-sdk/

http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/director-class-10

The PROS and CONS?

Director class is very simple and lightweight. And it has no known bugs. Used to be the only way until Storyboard was introduced a few months ago.
Story board is very flexible, and is officially supported.   But it is relatively new and has some minor bugs.