# Android Hash Key - cant connect with Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, hash, coronasdk

I have went threw all the steps, creating a key hash for android for my game build in corona. For 2 days I'm trying to figure it out and it just doesn't work. Feelling kinda desperate. :( Here are my steps:

- I have downloaded OPENSSL from Google in extracted it into C:\openssl
- I have the latest version of Java which is in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
- For testing I'm using the sample Facebook app provided with Corona. I have entered the AppId.
- I create the keyhash using this command:

*keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\tomaz.OXYLUS.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64*

- for password I enter android
- then I paste the generated key in my facebook developer account under Native Android App\ Key Hashes
- then I try to connect with the Corona Facebook app to Facebook, but it always says "loginCancelled". Also this error appears in the terminal window: *W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(29191): com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiException: Key hash EOw2r7Y4bNzFal-wFxLBGJQSxV8 does not match any stored key hashes.*

What am I missing? I also tryed this procedure with the original game key. No succes. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the OpenSSL from Google website and installed this one  http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html, which I found on Facebook. Now everything is working just fine. Thank you for all your efforts Abhishek.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to visit upload and register your apps in facebook developer? Before we can connect to facebook we need to register our application with the use of keyhash as identifier.

Comment: Yes, I did that. And also entered the generated hash key there. No succes. :(

Answer (score 0):

Once generate your key by code using the answer given in the link. Sometimes it returns different hash key . Chech the key in logcat and edit in **Facebook app setting**.[Facebook Integration in Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730848/facebook-integration-in-android-application/16734424#16734424)

Comment: Could you be more specific. I'm sorry, but I don't have any expirience with Project Manager. I work in Corona SDK. I have plugged in my phone on the computer, then started the comand line tool. There entered ADB LOGCAT, I copied the Hash key (which is btw completly different) and entered it into Facebook developer portal. No succes though. :(

Comment: Write the code on the link in your launcher activity and the hash key will be printed on your logcat.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't use eclipse. I'll develop in corona SDK and I believe corona doesn't give this option.

Comment: According to me there should be a launcher activity.

Comment: hm, couldn't find it. :( and also according to this post there are none:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083472/how-to-start-new-activity-in-corona

Comment: you can make new android application project and put code in the activity of that project as hash key system specific not application specific.

Answer (score 0):

Well i am facing same issue...so i solved error like. When i use this "**ionic cordova build android**" coming error invalid key hash facebook android but this thing work on production app "**ionic cordova build android --prod**", i hope it help you...